# css link can touch off transition？

Tags: css

2 simple html and css file

```css
/*main.css*/


 .test1.test2 {
        background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<!--index.html-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <style>
        .test1{
            background-color: green;
            transition: 2s
        }
        
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="test1 test2" style="height: 100vh">TEST</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open it in my browser, the transiton show up(from green to red). And what confuse me more is that when I add a script, the problem disappear.

```html
<!--index.html-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <!--Add a script, or a script link-->
    <script src="1.js"></script>
    <style>
        .test1{
            background-color: green;
            transition: 2s
        }
        
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="test1 test2" style="height: 100vh">TEST</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this, I add a script, and the problem disappear.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What problem? What's in the script? What are you trying to do?

Comment: the question is not clear but i can see that you want it green so remove the red in css

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression, my problem is not about the div, is the 2s transition(it is not supposed to have a gradul change from green to red, it should be red when i open the page, because i didn't use any trigger like :hover or js.), you can copy the code, and try it in your computer.

Comment: and the second html also have a main.css like before, i just didn't put it on the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your second example *"works"* and the problem *"disapears"* vs your first example is because you are using different CSS selectors to add the transition, **not because** you have included a script.

Your first example has a style that the second example does not have, `.test1.test2 {}`. This selector is overriding the selector `.test1 {}` because it is more specific, `0020` vs `0010`. If you add the CSS that is in the first example to the second example you get the same result.

#### Solution

Don't include the `.test1.test2` styles.

Comment: I will retract my comment in shame :(

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you want, but I think you want to have your `<div>` green. So just remove

```
.test1.test2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

from your code.

```html
<!--index.html-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <style>
        .test1{
            background-color: green;
            transition: 2s
        }
        
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="test1 test2" style="height: 100vh">TEST</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression, my problem is not about the div, is the transition, you can copy the code, and try it in your computer, the transition is not supposed to be shown up, because i didn't any trigger like :hover or js.

Comment: The transition is there by default because it's applied to the element from the get-go.

Comment: but if i move the content in main.css to the <head> in index.html, the gradual transiton won't show.